# SharePoint 2019 On Premise spfx js dev setup. which tools versions to serve helloworld?

Tags: npm, sharepoint, gulp, yeoman, spfx

I am trying to set a development environment in order to code spfx **webpart**s targeting **SP2019 on premise** sites.

After following the Microsoft documentation - including the almost hidden pages regarding whatever is not online - I came up with the folowing versions of the various tools :

- SPFX  1.4.1
- node  6.17.1
- npm   3.10.10
- gulp  3.9.1
- yo    2.0.6
- template @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0

I obviouly missed something since after installing globaly : node > gulp > gulp-cli > yo
I am unable to run yo. It throws

```
C:\Users\login\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:154
      options = {singleResult: !options.multiple, ...options};
                                                  ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\login\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\router.js:9:27)
```

It must be my third attempt to find the right versions since I first followed the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment
which starts by telling us to install the last LTS version of node before sending us to other pages at the bottom of the article to tell us in a convoluted whay that the last compatible version an old one. So I uninstalled, removed the appdata folders and temp trash left after uninstalling (great automation tools)

Is anyone around able to do list the versions and the order of installation required to create a webpart solution for SharePoint 2019 on premise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am developing on SharePoint 2019 with this dev setup:

- Node v8.17.0 (**this is Important**)
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
- gulp@3.9.1
- npm@6.13.4
- yo@3.1.1

Setup:

1. Install Node v8.17.0
2. `npm install gulp-cli@2.3.0 yo@3.1.1 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0 --global`

If you are developing also on SharePoint online my recommendation is to use nvm (node version manager), which allows to use different versions of Node. https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/

Comment: Thank you! That was it. A colleague managed to install it using node 10.24.1 as stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.